# Laravel subdomain call wrong controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I have a problem with my Laravel ( 4.2 ) route .

How do I make the following url call **pagedetail** controller .

- category.domain.com/detail/title/id/year/month/date **( when open
  category article detail )**
- category.domain.com/subcategory/detail/title/id/year/month/date **( when 
  open sub-category article detail )**

I have made one like this, but only succeeds when calling the article in the sub categories ( category.domain.com/subcategory/detail/id/year/month/date ) . And when i call artile in main category it return **NotFoundHttpException** .

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domaincategory}.domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('{category?}/detail/{title}/{id}/{year}/{month}/{date}', array('as' => 'read_news_detail', 'uses' => 'OnlineFrontPageController@pagedetail'));
    Route::get('{category?}', array('as' => 'online_category', 'uses' => 'OnlineFrontPageController@pagecategory'));

});
```

Comment: Do you mean subdomain.domain.com/bla/bla works but www.domain.com/bla/bla doesnt , right ?

Comment: no , i mean category.domain.com/detail/title/id/year/month/date not work , but category.domain.com/subcategory/detail/title/id/year/month/date work , with www or without www .